# where can I get list of google excluded words, like, to, is, am, in, of, the, ?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

where can I get list of google excluded words, like, to, is, am, in, of, the, ?

When a search is performed in google?

I hope you have understood what I want .. about the list of google excluded words when a user search in google?

Comment: This naturally begs the question, why do you need that list?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for are called "stop words" and Google has been moving toward a heuristic that's a *little* more complicated than a simple list - here's their stop words patent:

[Locating meaningful stopwords or stop-phrases in keyword-based retrieval systems](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm&r=1&p=1&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&S1=7,409,383.PN.&OS=pn/7,409,383&RS=PN/7,409,383)

Comment: They patented that?!